# Integrating SIP content with red5pro

Tags: video-streaming, sip, red5, broadcasting, red5pro

I have details for a SIP server account which is being used by a 3rd party software  and I need to broadcast a incoming stream from 3rd party software which uses SIP through streaming server like red5pro.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 Pro offers several injest endpoints like WebRTC, WebSockets, RTSP/RTP, RTMP. However, the server doesn't natively support SIP at this time so You would have to introduce Jitsi or Jain-SIP to the open source Red5 and then bundle that as a Red5 Pro plugin. You could additionally reach out to Red5 Pro if you are looking for this as a feature request.